# Angular 6 to open url in new window

Tags: window.open

I am looking for the following javascript equivalent code in angular 6 to open an url in a new window. The javascript snippet is herewith as follows:

```
window.open('/pageaddress.html', 
'winname', 'directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,     
 menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');
```

I managed to open the url in a new browser using the following code:

```
let params = `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no, width=0,height=0,left=-1000,top=-1000`;
let url = '/pageaddress.html';
window.open(url, 'winname', params);
```

This opens the url in new window with url link disabled.

Is there any way to hide the URL address?

Regards